# Make the variable available outside the function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables

I have the following code:

```
def Payment():
    print('The cost for''is 1£')
    print('Please insert coin')
    credit = float(input())
    while credit < 1:
       print('Your credit now is', credit,'£')
       print('You still need to add other',-credit+1,'cent')
       newcredit = float(input())
       credit = newcredit + credit
Payment()
print(credit)
```

Now I need to be able to read the variable "credit" after the while in the main code but I get the error

> NameError: name 'credit' is not defined

How can I extract the variable `credit` from the function `Payment` to use in the main program?

Comment: You could try passing it as a global variable using `global credit`.

Answer (score 3):

Return it as the functional result:

```
def Payment():

    print('The cost for''is 1£')
    print('Please insert coin')
    credit = float(input())

    while credit < 1:
       print('Your credit now is', credit,'£')
       print('You still need to add other',-credit+1,'cent')
       newcredit = float(input())
       credit = newcredit + credit

    return credit


balance = Payment()
print(balance)
```

Comment: You can also declare credit as a global variable, although that's not really good style

Comment: I'm well aware of that -- both that it's possible, and that it's bad style.  Teach them the paths ... :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should just `return` the variable from the function like @Prune showed.

But in case you literally want it as [`global`](https://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) variable you have to define it outside the function and use `global credit` inside your function (that will tell Python it should alter a variable outside of the function scope):

```
credit = 0

def Payment():
    global credit
    credit = float(input())
    while credit < 1:
        newcredit = float(input())
        credit = newcredit + credit
Payment()
print(credit)
```

But the alternative with `return` is much better, I just presented it because it was mentioned in the comments (twice).

Answer (score 0):

Aside from returning credit you can store that value into another variable and deal with it that way. In case you need to modify that credit variable further down. 
`new_variable = credit
print(new_variable)`

Answer (score 0):

This is easier than you think.
First, assign a variable named credit (out of the function). This will not interact with any functions.

```
credit = 0
```

Let your function be except with adding a parameter and an addition of a return statement.

```
    def Payment(currentcredit):
        ...
        return currentcredit - credit #lose credit after payment
```

Finally,

```
credit = Payment(credit)
```

The final code is

```
credit = 100
def Payment(currentcredit):
    print('The cost for''is 1£')
    print('Please insert a coin')
    credit = float(input())
    while credit < 1:
       print('Your credit is now', currentcredit,'£')
       print('You still need to add another',-credit+1,'cents!')
       newcredit = float(input())
       credit = newcredit + credit
    return currentcredit - credit
credit = Payment(credit)
print(credit)
```

**Output**

> **CON**: The cost for ' ' is 1£
>   **CON**: Please insert a coin
>   **ME**: 0.5
>   **CON**: Your credit is now 100£
>   **CON**: You still need to add another 0.5 cents!
>   **ME**: 49.5
>   *Variable "credit" updated to Payment(100) => 50*
>   **CON**: 50

[50 credit = 100 credit minus 50 credit lost]
Works like a charm.